# Javascript/HTML использование querySelector совместно с insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я хочу сделать выпадающий список с помощью insertAdjacentHTML, но есть проблема с определением, куда вставлять переменную, оно вставляется всегда в первый элемент, независимо от того, какая кнопка была нажата. Помогите вставить строку в элемент, который был нажат. Код и скриншот прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    function walletRowTemplate(adress, passPhrase, maticBalance, avaxBalance, trxBalance, ftmBalance, bnbBalance, ethBalance, usdBalance) {
    return `<tr id="ETH_${adress}" class="walletTableRow">
            <td class="wallet_num"></td>
            <td class="wallet_phrase">
                <span>${passPhrase}</span>
                <button onclick="copyToClipboard('${passPhrase}')"title="Копировать"><img src="public/icons/copy.png"></button>
            </td>
            <td class="wallet_MATIC_balance">${maticBalance}</td>
            <td class="wallet_AVAX_balance">${avaxBalance}</td>
            <td class="wallet_TRX_balance">${trxBalance}</td>
            <td class="wallet_SOL_balance">0</td>
            <td class="wallet_FTM_balance">${ftmBalance}</td>
            <td class="wallet_BNB_balance">${bnbBalance}</td>
            <td class="wallet_ETH_balance">${ethBalance}</td>
            <td class="wallet_USD_balance">${usdBalance}$</td>
            <td class="wallet_actions">
                <button onclick="updateWalletBalance('${adress}')"><img src="public/icons/magnifier.png"></button>
            </td>
            </tr>`
}

    function copyToClipboard(passPhrase) {
        query('#walletListTable tr .wallet_phrase').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${passPhrase}</li>`)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При клике возникает событие [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event), свойствами которого можно пользоваться:

```html
<td class="wallet_phrase">
  <span>span</span>
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard('atata')" title="Копировать">button</button>
  <button onclick="copyToClipboard('atata2')" title="Копировать">button</button>
</td>
<script>
  function copyToClipboard(passPhrase) {
    //console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(passPhrase);
    event.currentTarget.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>li</li>`)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, почти работает как надо. Осталось подправить, чтобы элемент вставлялся не в button, а в td (Как на скриншоте). Сейчас почитаю о event более подробно. Сейчас это выглядит так: https://ibb.co/9VvGSXW

Comment: Все, спасибо вам большое! Сделал event.currentTarget.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${adress}</li>`) и теперь все выводит как надо.

Answer (score -1):

querуSelector всегда выбирает первый элемент, а вам нужно выбрать тот, который относится к конкретной кнопке. Это можно сделать с помощь `this` и и навигации по DOM.

Comment: this внутри функции будет указывать на window,, и возвращать undefined в 'use strict'

Comment: @Jean-Claude Ну а кто об использовании внутри функции говорит?

Comment: ну тогда расширь ответ, а то не каждый поймет его.